# What is '::ffff:` in the returned IP address?

Tags: nestjs

Based on the following way I can get the user ip address:

```
@Get('ip')
public async getUserIp(@Ip:ip) {
    return {
        ip
    }
}

// OR

@Get('ip')
public async getUserIp(@Req() request: Request) {
    return {
        ip:request.ip
    }
}
```

This is the result of above API:

```
{
"ip": "::ffff:10.244.72.76"
}
```

what is **::ffff:**

Comment: This is the [IPv6 representation of an IPv4 address](http://mars.tekkom.dk/w/index.php/IPv4-Mapped_IPv6_Address).